# How to make an One-Liner list with multiple variables in Python?

Tags: python

I was interested whether I can define *ascii_combinations* list in one line and not using the loop I used in the following example...

```
ascii_printable = [chr(count) for count in range(32, 127)]
ascii_combinations = []

for x1 in ascii_printable:
    for x2 in ascii_printable:
        for x3 in ascii_printable:
            ascii_combinations.append(x1 + x2 + x3)
```

I wanted to create a list of all possible 3 characters long combinations using 95 single-character ASCII characters. I made it work using this code but as I managed to shorten *ascii_printable* into One-Liner, I was interested whether I can do the same thing with the other list.

Comment: See `itertools.product`

Comment: ascii_combinations = [x1+x2+x3 for x1 in ascii_printable for x2 in ascii_printable for x3 in ascii_printable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `itertools.product` as

```
from itertools import product

ascii_printable = [chr(count) for count in range(32, 127)]
ascii_combinations = [x1 + x2 + x3 for x1, x2, x3 in product(ascii_printable, repeat=3)]
```

Also `chr(count) for count in range(32, 127)` is way less clear than

```
from itertools import product
from string import printable

ascii_combinations = [x1 + x2 + x3 for x1, x2, x3 in product(printable[:-5], repeat=3)]
```

Lastly, comprehensions are nice but sometimes it's easier to think, imho, in terms of maps of iterables, thus

```
from itertools import product
from string import printable
list(map(''.join, product(printable[:-5], repeat=3)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to create a cartesian product, standard way to do so is using `itertools.product`.

```
import itertools

ascii_printable = [chr(count) for count in range(32, 127)]
ascii_combinations = [x1+x2+x3 for x1, x2, x3 in itertools.product(ascii_printable, repeat=3)]
```

Comment: Why can't you say itertools.product(ascii_printable, repeat=3)?

Comment: @GreenAsJade because I've forgot about this keyword argument. Fixed

Comment: You could use the `str.join` method, eg `[''.join(t) for t in product(ascii_printable, repeat=3)]`

Answer (score 0):

This results in True:

```
ascii_printable = [chr(count) for count in range(32, 127)]
ascii_combinations = []

for x1 in ascii_printable:
    for x2 in ascii_printable:
        for x3 in ascii_printable:
            ascii_combinations.append(x1 + x2 + x3)

test = [x1+x2+x3 for x1 in ascii_printable for x2 in ascii_printable for x3 in ascii_printable]

print(test == ascii_combinations)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact one liner equivalent of your code. (I've written ascii_printable as AP;count as c and ascii_combinations as AC)

```
AP = [chr(c) for c in range(32,127)]

AC = [x+y+z for x in AP for y in AP for z in AP]; print(AC)
```